# Efficiently find Unique triplets of three char vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, vector, unique

Given three arrays of char, say `size(a) = [N,80]`, `size(b) = [N,100]`;  `size(c) = [N,10]`;

When `N=5`
`a`, `b` and `c` look something like,

```
ans =

  5×80 char array

‘efawefref’
‘Afreafraef’
‘afeafefaef’
‘afeafeaffa’
‘afeafaefae’
```

I want to find the unique entries (not combinations), this is, the unique entries of `x = [a, b, c]`

Of course I can do `unique([a, b, c])` but this is terrible slow for this data. `N~1e7`

Example,

```
   a = [   'timon ';
        'simba ';
        'nala  ';
        'timon ';
        'mufasa'];

b = [   'boar   ';
        'lion   ';
        'lionese';
        'boar   ';
        'lion   '];

c = [   'chubby';
        'small ';
        'fat   ';
        'chubby';
        'fit   '];


unique([a,b,c],'rows')

ans =

  4×19 char array

    'mufasalion   fit   '
    'nala  lionesefat   '
    'simba lion   small '
    'timon boar   chubby'


size(unique([a,b,c],'rows'),1)

ans =

     4
```

IS there a smarter way to do this?

EDIT: results from answers
For entries of these sizes,

```
>> size(a)

ans =

    11724952          76

>> size(b)

ans =

    11724952          64

>> size(c)

ans =

    11724952           6
```

Results

@myradio

```
>> tic, size(unique(horzcat(a,b,c),'rows')), toc

ans =

     1038303         146

Elapsed time is 74.402044 seconds.
```

@gnovice 1

```
>> tic, size(unique(cellstr([a b c]))), toc

ans =

     1038303           1

Elapsed time is 77.044463 seconds.
```

@gnovice 2

```
>> tic, map = containers.Map(cellstr([a b c]), ones(length(a), 1)); size(map.keys.'), toc

ans =

     1038303           1

Elapsed time is 58.732947 seconds.
```

@Wolfie

```
>> tic, size(unique( [categorical(cellstr(a)),categorical(cellstr(b)),categorical(cellstr(c))], 'rows' )), toc

ans =

     1038303           3

Elapsed time is 189.517131 seconds.
```

@obchardon

```
>> tic, x = primes(2000); a1 = prod(x(a+0),2); b1 = prod(x(b+0),2); c1 = prod(x(c+0),2); size(unique([a1,b1,c1],'rows')), toc

ans =

     1038258           3

Elapsed time is 46.889431 seconds.
```

I am puzzled about this last one, I tried with other examples and it always gives a slightly lower value.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including an example expected input and output. If `unique` works, albeit slowly for large `N`, please show an example using `unique` so we can easily reproduce the results with any improvements

Comment: Are you sure that `x = [a,b,c];`, and subsequently `unique(x,'rows')`, is doing what you think it's doing?  Can you provide an example where you expect `unique` to actually remove duplicate rows?

Comment: so you want to concatenate a b and c together then find unique rows in the new concatenated variable? correct?

Comment: @PhilGoddard it is, but indeed I had a mistake I wantes the other dimension of the size of unique.

Comment: @Wolfie Changed for a more appealing theme

Comment: How long does it take on your computer ? And why should it be faster ? You've to repeat this operation several time ? What is the size of N in your data ?

Comment: @myradio: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @gnovice I am using matlab 2018b

Comment: @myradio: Hmm, I'm using R2018a and getting significantly different results. I get a factor of 7 speedup just using `cellstr` instead of the `'rows'` argument for `unique`. I'll update my answer in a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mimic the larger set of data in the question, I created the following randomized character arrays using [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
a = char(randi([65 90], [100 76]));      % Generate 100 76-character arrays
a = a(randi([1 100], [11724952 1]), :);  % Replicate rows: 11724952-by-76 result
b = char(randi([65 90], [100 64]));      % Generate 100 64-character arrays
b = b(randi([1 100], [11724952 1]), :);  % Replicate rows: 11724952-by-64 result
c = char(randi([65 90], [100 6]));       % Generate 100 6-character arrays
c = c(randi([1 100], [11724952 1]), :);  % Replicate rows: 11724952-by-6 result
```

With up to 100 unique strings in each of `a`, `b`, and `c`, this will yield close to 1,000,000 unique combinations when concatenated.

I then tested 3 solutions: the original using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), a variant that converts the character array to a cell array of strings using [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) to avoid using the `'rows'` argument, and one using a [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) object. The last one feeds the strings as keys to the `containers.Map` class (with dummy associated values) and lets it create a map that will have only the unique strings as its keys, which you can then extract.

Since these tests took a minimum of 1 minute to run, it wasn't feasible to use the more accurate timing routine [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) (which runs the function many times over to get an average measurement). I therefore used [`tic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html)/[`toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html). Here are some typical results using version R2018a:

```
>> clear d
>> tic; d = unique(horzcat(a, b, c), 'rows'); toc
Elapsed time is 726.324408 seconds.

>> clear d
>> tic; d = unique(cellstr([a b c])); toc
Elapsed time is 99.312927 seconds.

>> clear d
>> tic; map = containers.Map(cellstr([a b c]), ones(size(a, 1), 1)); d = map.keys.'; toc
Elapsed time is 89.853430 seconds.
```

The two faster solutions typically averaged around the same, with the `containers.Map` being slightly faster on average. They are both much faster than using `unique` with the `'rows'` argument, although this is in disagreement with the results in the post using version R2018b. Maybe `unique` had significant updates in the newer version, or maybe the specific content of the character arrays matters greatly (e.g. whether all strings repeat with roughly equal frequency, if the arrays are sorted versus unsorted, etc.).

Comment: I think the `cellstr` call itself is pretty slow too for a large `char` array, which isn't accounted for in your timings for either method presented, and should be included for comparison to the OP's method which operates directly on a large `char` array (the OP's edit covers this)

Comment: @Wolfie: Relative to the total amount of time, the `cellstr` call itself didn't make a lot of difference. However, my updated answer shows a big discrepancy in how `unique` might perform. Whether that's version-related or data-related I don't yet know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `unique` work faster with integer. If this is the case we could use this code to eventually speed up the operation:

```
%get at least ~200 primes numbers 
x = primes(2000); 

%prime multiplication will give an unique integer (prime factorization theorem)
a1 = prod(x(a+0),2); 
b1 = prod(x(b+0),2);
c1 = prod(x(c+0),2);

%Now we apply unique on integer instead of char
[~,ind] = unique([a1,b1,c1],'rows')

%Get the unique sentence.
r = [a(ind,:),b(ind,:),c(ind,:)]
```

Of course if N is too big the prime multiplication will give `Inf`.

EDIT:

As pointed out by @gnovice my hashing function is highly surjective (which can lead to collision).

So we can use another "hashing" function:

```
% each sentence are converted to an unique number
x = [a,b,c]+0*[10.^(0:18)].'

%get index
[~,ind] = unique(x)

%unique sentence:
r = [a(ind,:),b(ind,:),c(ind,:)]
```

This time there will be no collision, but again the sentences should be shorter than ~110 characters

Comment: if it's not faster I will delete my answer, let me know

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use `[a,b,c]-0` then for each character you will get its ASCII value, which is unique? Or am I missing an important point?

Comment: @Nicky I think this would work, but be much slower. `unique` is pretty slow with the `'rows'` argument when there are many columns, in this case you'd be going from 3 columns to many (the combined chars in `a`, `b`, and `c`), so you'll get a drastic slowdown.

Comment: This is actually in line with what I had in mind, I am testing performance now.

Comment: This actually runs very fast, but it's not giving me the same answer as @gnovice . Trying on his example I get a small diffference. Maybe there is a rounding accuracy problem?

Comment: The order change but the output should be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't always give unique integers. It will produce the same integer output for a rearrangement of characters. For example, these will all result in the same integer: `aaabbb`, `bbbaaa`, `ababab`. This is probably part of why OP is getting fewer unique values with this method. It is also likely resulting in `Inf` given that `N = 146`.

Comment: @gnovice ho... you're right... so the principle can stay unchanged but I need a better, fast, hashing function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the update, I will test later today.

Answer (score 1):

Categorical arrays are often quicker for this sort of thing, as they are roughly treated as ordinals internally.

```
% Set up your example
a = [ 'timon '; 'simba '; 'nala  '; 'timon '; 'mufasa'];
b = [ 'boar   '; 'lion   '; 'lionese'; 'boar   '; 'lion   '];
c = [ 'chubby'; 'small '; 'fat   '; 'chubby'; 'fit   '];

% Make the arrays larger and join into one big categorical array
k = [categorical(cellstr(a)),categorical(cellstr(b)),categorical(cellstr(c))];

% Get unique rows
u = unique( k, 'rows' );
```

We can make the `categorical(cellstr(...))` look a bit cleaner if operating on lots of variables by using an anonymous function:

```
cc = @(x) categorical(cellstr(x));
u = unique( [cc(a), cc(b), cc(c)], 'rows' );
```

**Edit:** Not sure this actually shows a speed-up, the `categorical` call is really slow for large char arrays,my test was rubbish.

Comment: Yep, I tested and this one is slower than the method I posted in the original question :(